# Exporting SSRS report to Excel Problems

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

So, I spent almost a day trying to get my SSRS report to look passable in Excel. Coworker wants to be able to print out information (using Fit All Columns on One Page), but the exported report text is getting cut off, when there's too many lines (since the max row height is 409 in Excel). I can click the cell and see where the overflow of text begins. I've gone through various forums to get troubleshooting advice, but nothing seems to help. I've tried making the font smaller, but it makes it pretty unreadable (it's already Arial Narrow font size 8). CanGrow is enabled in the report. I tried disabling, but I would have to make the rows super tall in Report Builder, but it still does not solve the problem of a cell only being 409 pixels tall.

Some of the rows have *a lot* of rows of data. I was thinking maybe splitting the data into two columns would be possible, but I'm assuming it isn't. 
Here's a (terrible) visualization of what's happening. Thank you.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Subject Name  |  Activity 1  | Name 1
|               |              | Name 2
|               |              | Name 3
|               ----------------------------------
|               |  Activity 2  | Name 1.....
|               |              | ........... 
|               |              | Name 50 (Imagine this is where it starts getting cut off in Excel)
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea, not sure if this would be an acceptable solution for you but I figured I would share.

In your example...

```
| Subject | Activity | Description |
| Joe     | Walking  | Overflows because too many characters (limit 10) |
```

You could potentially trim your description and add a description 2

```
| Subject | Activity | Description | Description2 |
| Joe     | Walking  | Overflows be| cause too many characters |
```

You would do this by replacing your item in the description data textbox with this expression:

```
=LEFT(Fields!Description.Value, 10)
```

Then add a Description2 column with this expression:

```
=MID(Fields!Description.Value, 10, LEN(Fields!Description.Value) - 10)
```